# Euler's criterion and Legendre symbol

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I am working on an exercise which is the following :

Let be $n$ an odd integer and $b$ such as $b \wedge n = 1$,  then

$(\frac{b}{n}) \equiv b^{(n-1)/2} \mod n$. (*)

- If $n$ is divisible by the square of a prime $p$, determine how to find an integer $b$ such as $b \wedge n = 1$ and $b^{(n-1)/2} \not \equiv \pm 1\mod n$.
- If $n = pq$ with $p$ and $q$ two distincts primes and $a$ an integer such as $(\frac{a}{n}) = -1$ and $a \equiv 1 \mod q$. Determine that the relation (*) is false for a such $a$. Prove that a such $a$ still exists.

So for the first question, we have $n = kp^2$ and we want $b \wedge n = 1$, i.e.  $b \wedge k = 1$ and $b \wedge p = 1$. But we also want $b^{(n-1)/2} \not \equiv \pm 1\mod n$, and $b^{(n-1)/2} \equiv (\frac{b}{n}) \mod n$ so it would mean that $(\frac{b}{n}) = 0$, i.e. $b | n$ ... So I don't really understand how to respond to this question :(

For the second one, I don't really know where to start...

Thank you for helping me to understand :)